# Facebook Canvas Unity3d like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Anybody know how to put in like or share button for a Unity3d game on the canvas? I've tried injecting the like button html code but have had difficulties. I'm trying to dynamically inject the HTML code for a "like button" onto the top banner of my Facebook Unity3d game. I've only been able to inject text at the top per the example given from the example given by Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/.../reference/current/CUI.

```
 string injection =
 "var headerElement = document.createElement('div');" +
 "headerElement.textContent = ('Check out our other great games: ...');" +
 "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
 "var insertionPoint = body.children[0]; " +
 "body.insertBefore(headerElement, insertionPoint);";
 Application.ExternalEval(injection);
```

The code from the Social Plugin section of the Facebook developer page I get is:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js...";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page:

```
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

The string code I have been injecting is:

```
string likeMe = 
    @"var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    js = document.createElement('script'); js.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    js.src = ""//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxx&version=v2.0"";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = ('Check out MEEEEEEE!!!!');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'fb-like');
    div.setAttribute('data-href', 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/');
    div.setAttribute('data-layout', 'standard');
    div.setAttribute('data-action', 'like');
    div.setAttribute('data-show-faces', 'false');
    div.setAttribute('data-share', 'false');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var insertionPoint = body.children[0];
    body.insertBefore(div, insertionPoint);";
```

Then I use `Application.ExternalEval(likeMe);`  (with x's in place of my appID).  However, the only I have ever gotten to show up is the 'Check out meeee!' just above my game.  Anybody have a solution?  I have been able to put the HTML code into a separate HTML file that calls my game and the "LIKE" button successfully shows up but not in the Facebook canvas by trying inject the HTML code dynamically as mentioned above.